# Can't compile controller Action with block request without specifying parameter type

Tags: scala, playframework

As the doc of Play 2.6 explains, you should be able to define an Action using a parameter block this way

```
class HomeController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents, system: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc) {
def action = Action { request => ...
```

Unfortunatey my IDE complains "cannot resolve method Action apply". As a workaround I had to specify the type of the request like this:

```
def action = Action {(request: Request[AnyContent]) =>
```

But it still disturb me not to be able to figure out why (i'm quite newby in scala btw). Thanks a lot to help me understand this puzzle.

scala 2.12.2 play 2.6.1

Comment: the error is probably "cannot resolve method Action apply with such signature" also could you please include the complete error message?

Comment: nevermind I reproduce your error. you won't face the problem with ```Action.async(parse.default){request => ???}``` but it still exists with ```Action(parse.default){request => ???}``` I noticed this change in play 2.6. can't figure out why inference doesn't work in case of a synchronous action. this to me seems like one of those compiler confusions caused where there is method overloading

Comment: hm strange, one of the overloaded apply methods should pick this up -- what is the return type of your partial function `Request[AnyContent] => ?`